# VB.NET Resize Form and Detect Size In TextBox

Tags: forms, textbox, resize, size, detect

Got two textbox's one represents the form's width, and the another height.

When the form loads it displays the size of the form's width, and height in each textbox.

When you resize the form it'll automatically update the text in the texbox's and tell you what the form's current size is.

How can I do this?

---

I used the code below so you can set the size you want and then it applys it to the form's size, but still haven't figured out how to automatically detect the form's width, and height when it's resized.

```
Private sizew As Integer
Private sizey As Integer

sizew = TextBox1.Text
sizey = TextBox2.Text
Me.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(sizew, sizey)
```

---

Figured out what I was doing wrong. For those that wonder how to do this, here's the code below.

```
Private sizew As Integer
Private sizey As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    TextBox1.Text = Me.Size.Width()
    TextBox2.Text = Me.Size.Height()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.SizeChanged
    TextBox1.Text = Me.Size.Width()
    TextBox2.Text = Me.Size.Height()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handle the `SizeChanged` event and read `Me.Size`.

Answer (score 1):

put a timer on the form and set the interval 100 then put this code on it

```
TextBox1.Text = Me.Size.Width()
TextBox2.Text = Me.Size.Height()
```

Note: Make sure the timer is enabled